# Why am I getting segmentation fault for malloc() while using pointer to pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I don't understand why this works:

```
void main() { 
    int *  b;
    b = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
    *b = 1;
    printf("*b = %d\n", *b);
}
```

while this does not (gets segmentation fault for the `malloc()`):

```
void main() {

    int ** a;
    int    i;

    for (i = 0; i<= 3; i++) {
        a[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
        *(a[i]) = i;
        printf("*a[%d] = %d\n", i, *(a[i]));
    }
}
```

since  I find `a[i]` is just like `b` in the first example.

BTW, `a[i]` is equal to `*(a+i)`, right?

Comment: Use `int main(void)` henceforth.`void main()` is not portable.

Comment: Also [never cast the result of `malloc`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858).

Comment: @linusz `a[i]` is indeed equal to `*(a+i)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to allocate memory for `a` first, so that you can access its members as `a[i]`.

So if you want to allocate for 4 `int *` do

```
a = malloc(sizeof(int *) * 4);

for (i = 0; i<= 3; i++) {
  ...
}
```

or define it as array of integer pointers as

```
int *a[4];
```

Comment: @Rüppell'sVulture, not sure what are you asking.

Comment: Nothing,there was a misunderstanding about the `.....` part.I thought you had supplanted the `malloc()` segment to outside the loop.But it works fine when we use `int **a = malloc(sizeof(int *) * 4);` and leave the rest of the program intact.Maybe that's what you meant and I misread it.

Answer (score 1):

a is a 2 dimensional pointer, you have to allocate both dimension.
b is a 1 dimensional pointer, you have to allocate only one dimension and that's what you're doing with

```
b = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

So in order the second example to work you have to allocate the space for the pointer of pointer

```
void main() {

int ** a;
int    i;
a = (int**)malloc(4*sizeof(int*));

for (i = 0; i<= 3; i++) {
    a[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    *(a[i]) = i;
    printf("*a[%d] = %d\n", i, *(a[i]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The allocated pointer is written to uninitialized memory (you never set `a` to anything), causing undefined behavior.

So no, it's not at all equivalent to the code in the first example.

You would need something like:

```
int **a;

a = malloc(3 * sizeof *a);
```

first, to make sure `a` holds something valid, *then* you can use indexing and assign to `a[0]`.

Further, this:

```
a[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

doesn't make any sense. It's assigning to `a[i]`, an object of type `int *`, but allocating space for `sizeof (int)`.

Finally, [don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).

Answer (score 0):

actually malloc it's not that trivial if you really want safe and portable, on linux for example malloc could return a positive response for a given request even if the actual memory it's not even really reserved for your program or the memory it's not writable.

For what I know both of your examples can potentially return a seg-fault or simply crash.

@ruppells-vulture I would argue that malloc is really portable and "safe" for this reasons.